# Building Comment Model Django

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
```

> NameError: name 'Post' is not defined

After this code make migrations also giving this error post is not defined. A lot of people work with this code in different sites. Why its not working every time showing `Post` is not defined. What can i do? Please help.

Comment: In order to help you with this, we need to see your project structure and where the `Post` model is defined.

Comment: https://djangocentral.com/creating-comments-system-with-django/

Comment: This is the link of it.at the first step i stucked .app name '  blog'

Comment: and where is your `Post` model defined?

Comment: https://djangocentral.com/creating-comments-system-with-django/

Comment: This is the link of it.at the first step i stucked .app name ' blog'

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you are following has a **"Pre-Requirements"** section. The `Post` model is defined in a previous step of that tutorial.

For learning purposes, I suggest you follow the official Django tutorial. It is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: THank you @Gokhan Sari.Yes.Today.i see the Post Model in his previous step...